# Motion of Fallopian tube fimbriae

Tags: human-anatomy, reproduction

The fimbriae at the ovary end of Fallopian tubes are described as ["sweeping" eggs from ovaries into the tubes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallopian_tube):

> When ovulation is about to occur, the sex hormones activate the fimbriae, causing them to swell with blood and hit the ovary in a gentle, sweeping motion. An oocyte is released from the ovary into the peritoneal cavity and the cilia of the fimbriae sweep the ovum into the Fallopian tube.

Is there more detail known about the "gentle, sweeping motion" of the fimbriae?  For example, is it a single swelling "sweep" per cycle?  Is the motion of the fimbriae against the ovary isolated from or accentuated by other movement of the body?